# How to get Tailwind's built-in CSS Purge to purge plugin CSS

Tags: css, postcss, tailwind-css, css-purge

I'm including Tailwind CSS in my project using PostCSS, and have Tailwind's built-in Purge implementation working great for the core library (in `style.pcss` below). However, I am also including `@tailwind/typography` as a plugin and its selectors aren't being purged.

```js
// postcss.config.js

const cssnano = require('cssnano')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'), 
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? require('autoprefixer') : null,
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? cssnano({ preset: 'default' }) : null
  ]
}
```

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography')
  ],
  purge: [
    './build/*.html',
    './build/**/*.html'
  ],
}
```

```
// style.pcss

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 2):

I Ran into the same thing!

There is a note about this on the typography README:

> https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography#purging-unused-styles

...and more details in the tailwindscss documentation:

> https://tailwindcss.com/docs/controlling-file-size#removing-all-unused-styles

Here is what your `tailwind.config.js` should probably look like:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography')
  ],
  purge: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: 'all',
    content: [
      './build/*.html',
      './build/**/*.html'
    ],
    options: {
      whitelist: []
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Oh, also may want to use `enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` to keep dev builds fast.